# Jquery ajax result not working on chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have a problem with my jquery ajax on chrome. Ajax will echo result like this:

```
1||result goes here
```

Here is the ajax script:

```
$("#load_cards").click(function() {
        $("#load_cards").fadeOut('fast');
        var form_data = {
            query: 'cardpack',
            page: page,
            pack: pack
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data: form_data,
            success: function(response)
            {
                response_d = response.split("||");
                response_message = parseInt(response_d[0]);
                response_html = response_d[1];

                if (response_message == 1) {
                    hist = $("#card_pack_list").html();
                    $("#card_pack_list").html(hist+response_html);
                    page = page+1;
                }
                else {

                }
                $("#load_cards").fadeIn('fast');
            }
        });
    });
```

The problem is that firefox and opera recognizes response_message as 1 but chrome does not. Why is that and how can i overcome it? I am running the script on xampp virtual server.

Comment: What is the value of `response_message` in Chrome?

Comment: do a `console.log(response);` and check the result in chrome.

Comment: If i put alert(response_message) in the code then it returns NaNa in chrome and 1 in firefox.

Comment: Do `console.log( response )` and look in the console as Zim says. You're not getting the response you expect.

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that Chrome goes in "success" callback ?

If not, try to add "complete" and "error" callback to the ajax call and see what happened :

```
success: function(response) {
    console.log("success callback");
    ...
},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("error callback : " + textStatus);
},
complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    console.log("complete callback : " + textStatus);
}
```

Comment: I think it does, other way the alert command after $("#load_cards").fadeIn('fast'); wouldnt work.

Comment: It depends, where is your alert exactly ?